# Magento admin menu with file upload

Tags: csv, menu, magento-1.9.2, import-products

I have developed a website in magento version 1.9.2, i have lot of products in `excel`, so I want to upload this file in magento admin, for that how to create menu and upload file in magento back end, I have just googled and founded some solutions but none of them working.

I am new in magento.

Comment: you can try [magmi](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Comment: Actually i can update / add products,  i want create menu in admin, in that menu upload file (excel). i want this.

Answer (score 0):

To upload product in magento admin no need to create menu, Magento already give a tab

```
system -> import/export -> import
```

or

```
 system -> import/export -> Dataflow - profiles
```

Here you will able to upload bulk products using CSV

Comment: i want to create new products, i mean already having some simple products in the site, i want to create configurable products, for configurable products details i will take any of the simple products details.

Comment: Do one thing: Manually create  a configurable product in backend and export product CSV from above path, So that you will familiar to configurable product formate.

Comment: i can understand, but what client expecting was he want to create configurable products, in the excel he will give New-sku existing-sku New sku will be configurable products, existing sku is simple products, so that simple products details i want apply for configurable products. these are all i have done getting values and updating, what i want was create menu in admin and upload excel file, so the excel file want store any where in the server or root folder,

Comment: That's why I am asking, Configurable products have diffrent row for their details and associated products have differ row, You have to fill row for configurable products.

Comment: Ram creating the products these are i will take care, i want to create a menu in admin AND in that i want upload file functionality. so please help me for this

Comment: For this you have to create a custom module for custom backend form(file upload), Hope this will help you :

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-back-end-configuration-in-magento--cms-23265

Comment: Actually i have created menu next to system. it's showing empty page. in that page i want upload file. so you please teach me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import all products to your website,
just follow the following instructions.

1. First of all, create all categories and create one product in your website,
2. After this, export that data and keep that with you.
3. Now arrange the data which you want to import, that total have to be arrange in the format of your exported data.
4. After arranged you can easily import the data into your website which you want to import newly in usual manner.
5. Then go to system-->import/Export-->Data flows-->Follow that rules...

Comment: i can understand, but what client expecting was he want to create configurable products, in the excel he will give                                                                 New-sku   existing-sku            New sku will be configurable products, existing sku is simple products, so that simple products details i want apply for configurable products. these are all i have done getting values and updating, what i want was create menu in admin  and upload excel file, so the excel file want store any where in the server or root folder,

Comment: you can store at anywhere i.e., in your pc also. y because, you can upload and save the profile before run the profile. so dont worry

Comment: Everyday client he will upload the file, for that only he want like this